# Is it possible in c++ to get as an string the name of a variable that was passed as a param?

Tags: c++

I will like to be able to do something like this

```
int myVar = 3;

void logger(int param) {
  std::cout << nameOf(param) << ": " << param << std::endl;
}

logger(myVar); // prints "myVar: 3"
```

Comment: This is not possible with a function. Identifiers (the name of variables) do not exist at run time. You can try to achieve this with macros (`#define`) to construct a string literal based on an identifier at compile time. See [Stringification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989730/stringification-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Only possible with macros.

Comment: How that macro will be?

Comment: Something like `#define LOG(x) logger(x, #x)` ... assuming `void logger(int param, std::string const&)` or such.

Comment: No, you cannot do what you asked. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Does [how to print many variables with there name and their corresponding value in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215959/7582247) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this in the C++ language yet, since there is no reflection facility to do this.

However, you can use preprocessor macros to achieve the effect you want. **Note that macros are dangerous, and should be avoided as far as possible.**

First, write an implementation function that takes the parameter value, and the parameter name, like this:

```
void logger_impl(int param, std::string param_name) {
  std::cout << param_name << ": " << param << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can write a macro that generates a string from the variable name in the call site, using `#` (the stringification operator), and then uses that string in the call to the implementation function:

```
#define logger(p) logger_impl(p, #p)
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s7fdvG).

Comment: Was traumatized early in my career by a macro implementation of `strlen`. Soaked up half a day figuring out what happened during a time I didn't have half a day to spare. Compiler messages are better these days, but I also know how to read them better.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, I've had lots of small annoyances over the years. Can't stand macros really, and had to think for a few minutes if I even wanted to post an answer :p

Comment: I will use this only for debugging, no plans to commit this into the project.

Comment: could be possible to allow to pass infinite number of variables?
such as "logger(param1, param2)"

Comment: I assume you mean arbitrary? Sure, you can have another macro that takes in multiple parameters, and calls this macro indirectly.

Comment: Do you know about an example to do it?

Comment: Search for "variadic macros" and try solving it yourself. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @cigien Its actually significantly harder to implement than a single argument version. I don't think you can achieve it without first implementing some form of macro for-each.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's relative, but yeah, I probably made it sound easier than I should have. Still, no point dissuading the OP from trying it out themselves.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm, really? I've tried to forget everything I know about macros ;) but I think an additional variadic macro would suffice here. I could be wrong, and I'll have to write it out, to be sure.

Comment: I tried to implement it but failed, any suggestions?

Comment: @ellipticaldoor If you've tried, and haven't found a solution, you can post a new question.

Comment: Calling macros "dangerous", particularly when you show a completely non-dangerous example, is a bit of a reach.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yeah, I see what you mean, I didn't have the disclaimer in the original answer. OTOH it's hard to tell when they're actually dangerous or not. And when they go wrong, it's really bad, so I do see the point of view that says warn up front.

Comment: \*shrug\* I've never had a "really bad" experience. Maybe your macros were truly awful ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well, my macros have always been absolutely perfect, it's other people's macros that are the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

Look at the following example:

```cpp
#include <string> 

// add the following macro
#define NAMEOF(x) #x

int main(){
    int myvar{ 5 };
    std::cout << NAMEOF(myvar) << "=" << myvar << std::endl; // myvar=5
 
   // it could also be stored in a variable 
    std::string myvarname{ NAMEOF(myvar) };

    return 0;
}
```