# C++ variadic dump macro?

Tags: c++, c++20

How can I define a macro that allows me to "dump" multiple variables to my terminal? e.g.

```cpp
DUMP(foo, bar, baz);
```

Would print:

```
my_file.cpp:100: foo="value of foo", bar="barval", baz="baz's val"
```

I've got it working for a single arg:

```cpp
#define DUMP(val) std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " << #val << "=" << (val) << std::endl
```

And I know I can make a variadic macro by defining it like `DUMP(args...)` but then I don't know how to expand that out properly into an ostream.

Comment: Since C++20 you don't need macros for this anymore. It introduces [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Comment: Nevermind, you still need macros to stringify your arguments.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ya. Good tip about `std::source_location` tho, I'm sure that'll come in handy later. Thanks

Comment: Have you already read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments ?

Comment: @Bob__ I've seen similar answers but I don't know how to get the arg names out of `__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: Perhaps helpful: [how to print many variables with there name and their corresponding value in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213475/how-to-print-many-variables-with-there-name-and-their-corresponding-value-in-c/64215959#64215959)

Comment: @mpen I added a `source_location` version to the old answer there. It still requires a macro to expand the variable names though. I couldn't think of a way to get rid of that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Cool! That's even better. Thank you 

Comment: @mpen Cheers! Yeah, I noticed that one now gets the full signatures of the functions **and** one even gets template parameters. `source_location` seems really nice!