# '.' unexpected in macro parameter list, in `#define error(args...)`

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I use this define in c++ to debug my variables it works in clion and codeblocks but does not work in visual studio 22.

Error C2010 '.': unexpected in macro parameter list codeforces

the file name is "codeforces"

```cpp
#define error(args...) { string _s = #args; replace(_s.begin(), _s.end(), ',', ' '); stringstream _ss(_s); istream_iterator<string> _it(_ss); err(_it, args); }
void err(istream_iterator<string> it) {}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void err(istream_iterator<string> it, T a, Args... args) {
    cerr << *it << " = " << a << endl;
    err(++it, args...);
}
```

I use this code below instead but it's not functional if there is alot of variables since i'll need to copy-paste is alot

```cpp
#define error(s) cout << #s << " = " << s << endl;
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: The syntax that you are using is not standard C++. It is a GCC extension. But the same functionality for variadic macros is standardized as `__VA_ARGS__` since C++11. Whatever source you used to learn that syntax is pretty out-dated and should have told you that this is a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `args...` is not standard C++. To capture everything in the parentheses of a macro, simply use `...` and then refer to it through `__VA_ARGS__`.
See [GCC Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), and [cppreference: Replacing text macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).

Besides that, you should also minimize the use of macros as much as possible.

> ```cpp
> #define error(args...) { string _s = #args; replace(_s.begin(), _s.end(), ',', ' '); stringstream _ss(_s); istream_iterator<string> _it(_ss); err(_it, args); }
> ```

You only need the macro so that you can call `do_error` and give it the string representation of the passed expression at the same time.
The rest can just be a variadic function template:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void do_error(std::string_view text, const Args&... args) {
    std::string _s(text);
    // TODO: this code is very naive and not safe against commas
    //       within string literals or parentheses
    std::replace(_s.begin(), _s.end(), ',', ' ');
    std::stringstream _ss(_s);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(_ss);
    err(it, args...);
}

// note: __VA_OPT__ (C++20) is needed to handle empty lists correctly.
//       There exist less elegant workarounds, e.g. you could set up
//       do_error()'s returned type to give you the syntax:
//         do_error(#__VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define error(...) do_error(#__VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Also note that your `err` function template can be improved:

```cpp
template <typename... Args>
void err(std::istream_iterator<std::string> it, const Args&... args) {
    // fold expression (C++17)
    ((std::cerr << *it++ << " = " << args << std::endl), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct preprocessor syntax would be `...` for the parameter and `#__VA_ARGS__` for its expansion:

```cpp
#define error(...)                               \
    {                                            \
        string _s = #__VA_ARGS__;                \
        replace(_s.begin(), _s.end(), ',', ' '); \
        stringstream _ss(_s);                    \
        istream_iterator<string> _it(_ss);       \
        err(_it, __VA_ARGS__);                   \
    }
```

---

Another, not so macro intense, version could be to pass on the stringified `#__VA_ARGS__` to a C++ function template. I made a pre- C++20 and a C++20 version for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215959/7582247) and here's the C++20 [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/no1ofexsf).

Comment: The syntax used by OP is I think a pre-standardization syntax for variadic macros used by GCC.

Comment: @user17732522 Could be. It's not in the standard though so using the standard way would make it more probable to work in Visual Stuio. ... and you are correct about the missing `#`. My mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: I think it looks good now. Only issue I see is that it will fail for empty argument list because of the expansion at the end, but that applies (I think) to the original version as well.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for checking. Yes, I think `__VA_OPT__(,)` is needed even there.